# I need help fixing the mutant table error

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have the next trigger

```
create or replace trigger Overwrite 
before insert on Comments 
Compound trigger 
declare

begin for each row 
declare
num number; 
begin

select count('x') into num
from comments
where title = :new.title 
and director = :new.director
and club = :new.club
and nick = :new.nick;

if num != 0 then
    delete from Comments
    where title = :new.title 
    and director = :new.director
    and club = :new.club
    and nick = :new.nick;
end if;
end;
```

And when I do a massive insert, I get the mutant table error

```
insert into Membership(nick, club, mentor, type, req_date, inc_date, end_date, req_msg, acc_msg) values('davina', 'Fellowship of the Correct', 'adalbi', 'I', sysdate-2, sysdate, null, 'sdfghjhgfd', '23456543dcvbh'); 
insert into Proposals values ('O', 'Tim Blake Nelson', 'Fellowship of the Correct', 'davina', sysdate, 'asdkhaskd', 'lakshndlkjasdlkjasdfhasdjklhasdfjhkladfsjlhjklashjklds'); 
insert ALL 
    into comments (club, nick, msg_date, title, director, subject, message, valoration) values ('Fellowship of the Correct', 'ecp', sysdate-3, 'O', 'Tim Blake Nelson', 'asd', 'adsfasdfasdf', 10)
    into comments (club, nick, msg_date, title, director, subject, message, valoration) values ('Fellowship of the Correct', 'ecp', sysdate-2, 'O', 'Tim Blake Nelson', 'asd', 'adsfasdfdfghdfghasdf', 10)
    into comments (club, nick, msg_date, title, director, subject, message, valoration) values ('Fellowship of the Correct', 'ecp', sysdate-1, 'O', 'Tim Blake Nelson', 'asd', 'adsfasdfwertwerasdf', 10)
    into comments (club, nick, msg_date, title, director, subject, message, valoration) values ('Fellowship of the Correct', 'ecp', sysdate, 'O', 'Tim Blake Nelson', 'asd', 'adsfasdewrbtvwfasdf', 10)
select * from dual;
```

The problem is that when doing a simple insertion I don't have a mutant table problem, but when doing massive insertions the mutant table error occurs, which I don't see very well why it occurs and I don't see how to fix it either, if someone knows and could explain to me how to fix it and why it occurs it would be good.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I agree with the other answer that this isn't the best way to achieve this, there is a way to to it.  You were on the right track with a `COMPOUND TRIGGER`.  Check this out:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CMP_COMMENTS_DUP
FOR INSERT ON COMMENTS
COMPOUND TRIGGER
  TYPE lt_commentRows IS TABLE OF COMMENTS%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  l_tComments lt_commentRows;
  l_nIndex INTEGER := 1;

  AFTER EACH ROW
  IS
  BEGIN
    l_tComments(l_nIndex).title:= :NEW.title;
    l_tComments(l_nIndex).director:= :NEW.director;
    l_tComments(l_nIndex).club:= :NEW.club;
    l_tComments(l_nIndex).nick:= :NEW.nick;
    l_nIndex := l_nIndex+1;
  END AFTER EACH ROW;

  AFTER STATEMENT IS
  BEGIN
    FORALL i IN INDICES OF l_tComments
      DELETE FROM comments c
      WHERE c.title= l_tComments(i).title
      AND c.director= l_tComments(i).director
      AND c.club= l_tComments(i).club
      AND c.nick= l_tComments(i).nick
      AND c.msg_date <> (SELECT MIN(c2.msg_date)
                         FROM comments c2
                         WHERE c2.title= l_tComments(i).title
                         AND c2.director= l_tComments(i).director
                         AND c2.club= l_tComments(i).club
                         AND c2.nick= l_tComments(i).nick);  
  END AFTER STATEMENT;
END;
/
```

This will populate the associative array for each row after it is inserted.  Then during the `AFTER STATEMENT` portion (When table manipulation is allow again), it will delete duplicate rows keeping the earliest message by msg_date.

Comment: Thanks, its works perfectly but in the last select its with MAX(c2.msg_date).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a trigger for what should be implemented as a `unique` constraint?

```
alter table comments add constraint unq_comments_4
    unique (title, director, club, nick);
```

Comment: It's a college job, I was asked to do it with triggers

Comment: its not for restrict the comment, its for overwrite the comment

Comment: @GerardoHernandez - So your assignment is to use a trigger to turn an INSERT into an UPDATE? What a deeply terrible use of triggers. It deserves some kind of prize.